# Performance monitor on Vpn

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I am using the windows performance monitor classes in my C# project to measure bytes sents etc via the network card and all seems fine. I am using the network index number to determine the network interface to use to record performance data. I can see the network index numbers via the command prompt (netsh int ipv4 show int)

However, I have connected to the vpn and changed the network index number to refer to the vpn and when I try to read the performance monitor "nextValue()" I get an exception.

So my question is, can I use the "System.Diagnostic.PerformanceCounters" to get packets sent etc from the VPN or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the powershell performance counters, they have a lot of power...

The way guide to the power shell commands (import-counter) can be found here..

http://ss64.com/ps/

I have added some example code below for you to see how they are called:

```
private static void LoadBLG(string CounterPath)
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddCommand("import-counter");
            ps.AddArgument(CounterPath);

            Console.WriteLine(CounterPath);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");

            foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
            {
                if (result.ImmediateBaseObject is PerformanceCounterSampleSet)
                {
                    PerformanceCounterSampleSet Counters = result.ImmediateBaseObject as PerformanceCounterSampleSet;
                    foreach (PerformanceCounterSample sample in Counters.CounterSamples)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1}",
                            sample.Path, sample.RawValue);
                }
            } // End foreach.
```

Good luck 
Matthew